# Extracting the sum of elements with xpathsapply from an XML file using "R"

Tags: xml, r, xpath

Let's assume we have the following XML file:

```html
<XML>
  <A>
    <B>
      <ID>1</ID>
    </B>
    <C>
      <D>10</D>
      <D>20</D>
    </C>
  </A>
  <A>
    <B>
      <ID>2</ID>
    </B>
    <C>
      <D>30</D>
      <D>50</D>
    </C>
  </A>
</XML>
```

Now I want to get a table (data frame or list) from it by using "R" (with "xpathSApply") with the ID as first column and the sum of the associated "D"s. So in this example the result should look like this:

```html
ID  |  sum(D)
----+--------
1   | 30
2   | 80
```

The xml file is just an example. In reality it contains much more elements and the number of D elements per A element is variable.

Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
library(XML)
lst <- xmlToList('file.xml')
do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, function(x) {x1 <- unlist(x)
        data.frame(ID=x1[1], Sum_D=sum(as.numeric(x1[-1])))}))
#   ID Sum_D
#A   1   30
#A1  2   80
```

Or may be if the length of `D` elements are the same

```
xl <- xmlParse('file.xml')
ID <- xpathSApply(xl, '//ID', xmlValue)
Sum_D <- colSums(matrix(as.numeric(xpathSApply(xl, '//D', 
                xmlValue)), ncol=length(ID)))

 data.frame(ID, Sum_D)
#  ID Sum_D
#1  1   30
#2  2   80
```